# How can I convert this SQL query to Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

One of our teams asked this question earlier today, and there aren't any right answers still. Perhaps the way he worded the question wasn't correct—all in all, this is the SQL query I want to convert to Laravel Eloquent:

```sql
SELECT * FROM drivers 
    where driver_number 
NOT IN (SELECT driver_number FROM buses) 
    AND station_id = 2 OR driver_number = 'Dr_02'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
Driver::whereNotIn('driver_number', Buse::select('driver_number'))
       ->where('station_id', 2)
       ->orWhere('driver_number', 'Dr_02');
```

If the *Buse* select gives you an error, add the *get* method at the end of it:

```
Buse::select('driver_number')->get()
```